# FastDateFormat parsing issue

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to parse with `FastDateFormat` the String "0759" and "1401" but getting a `ParsingException`.

It worked fine with `SimpleDateFormat` but I want to avoid using it as it's not thread safe. I'm checking if the current time is within a specific time-frame to take additional actions. I want to use `FastDateFormat` instead for the code below. Please advise

```
try{
SimpleDateFormat time_to_string = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
        String executionEndTime = time_to_string.format(stepExecution.getEndTime());

        Date emailDeliveryStartTime =
                (Date) time_to_string.parse("0759");
        Date emailDeliveryEndTime =
                (Date) time_to_string.parse("1401");
        Date currentSystemTime = (Date) time_to_string.parse(executionEndTime);

        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.setTime(emailDeliveryStartTime);

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(emailDeliveryEndTime);

        Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar3.setTime(currentSystemTime);

        Date isEmailTime = calendar3.getTime();

        if (isEmailTime.after(calendar1.getTime()) && isEmailTime.before(calendar2.getTime())) {
            //return flowexecutionstatus 
        }
} catch (ParseException ex) {
        //log message
}
```

Comment: what is the datatype returned by `stepExecution.getEndTime()`?

Comment: This is a Spring batch job. So stepExecution has the getEndTime() method that tells you the time when the batch job has finished running

Comment: if that is so why are you converting time to string and again back to time?

Comment: So I can be converted into the right format. At least that was my thought process which might be wrong but besides that changing into FastDateFormat is what I'm really looking help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentations of [`FastDateFormat.parse(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) states:

> **Equivalent to `DateFormat.parse(String)`.** *See [DateFormat.parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html?is-external=true#parse(java.lang.String))* for more information.

Now the documentation of [`DateFormat.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html?is-external=true#parse(java.lang.String)) states:

> **Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date.**
>   The method may not use the entire text of the given string.
>
> *See the [parse(String, ParsePosition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition))* method for more information on
>   date parsing.

And the documentation of [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) states:

> This parsing operation uses the `calendar` to produce a Date. **As a
>   result, the `calendar`'s date-time fields and the TimeZone value may
>   have been overwritten, depending on subclass implementations.** Any
>   TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone
>   may need to be restored for further operations.

So, what we can make out from the above is that the `FastDateFormat.parse(String)` basically uses a `calendar` object and then overwrites the date-time fields of that object and then generates the `Date` object from it.

But there is a subtle difference in the working of `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)`. There is no overriding of `parse(String)` method but the `parse(String, ParsePostion)` is overridden and its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) states:

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. **All of the
>   calendar's date-time fields are cleared before parsing, and the
>   calendar's default values of the date-time fields are used for any
>   missing date-time information.** For example, the year value of the
>   parsed Date is 1970 with GregorianCalendar if no year value is given
>   from the parsing operation. The TimeZone value may be overwritten,
>   depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in text. Any
>   TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone
>   may need to be restored for further operations.

In other words I feel that `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` is able to provide with the desired result as it substitutes the default values for the missing fields, where as `FastDateFormat.parse(String)` is unable to parse as you have missing fields in your supplied date time string which it is unable to replace.

Finally, though you have not shown how you have instantiated the `FastDateFormat` variable. If you have instantiated as :

```
FastDateFormat time_to_string = FastDateFormat.getInstance();
```

then I would suggest that you use the following:

```
FastDateFormat time_to_string = FastDateFormat.getInstance("HHmm");
```